How to programmatically get temporary AWS credentials using IAM Roles Anywhere?
We have a non-AWS Kotlin application that needs to download and process files from AWS S3 storage outside of our organization. Vendor didn't provide us with permanent credentials and instructed to use aws_signing_helper instead — a command-line tool that uses certificate and private key to generate temporary credentials.
Is there a better way to get temporary credentials, rather than having this command line tool running on the same machine with our application? I would expect to have a way of doing it using an SDK, but I'm unable to find any examples for it in Amazon documentation.

I had exact requirements for JAVA and Spring boot based code.
I had created a blog relating to the similar problem. Link here
The example code repository is on Github here
The code refreshes the AWS credentials just before expiry of the previous set of credentials. This action is configurable based on a simple boolean flag.
With this approach, no need to create a customization around the build package to mandatory include the aws signing helper
I hope you can use most of the code provided in my links.
Happy to assist further
Example configuration:-
@Configuration
public class AwsConfig {

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider(final AwsRolesAnywhereProperties awsRolesAnywhereProperties,
                                                         final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        var rolesAnywhereCredentialsProvider = new IAMRolesAnywhereSessionsCredentialsProvider
                .Builder(awsRolesAnywhereProperties, objectMapper)
                .asyncCredentialUpdateEnabled(true)
                .build();
        return rolesAnywhereCredentialsProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProviderV2(final AwsRolesAnywhereProperties awsRolesAnywhereProperties,
                                                           final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        var rolesAnywhereCredentialsProvider = new IAMRolesAnywhereSessionsCredentialsProvider
                .Builder(objectMapper)
                .roleArn(awsRolesAnywhereProperties.getRoleArn())
                .profileArn(awsRolesAnywhereProperties.getProfileArn())
                .trustAnchorArn(awsRolesAnywhereProperties.getTrustAnchorArn())
                .encodedPrivateKey(awsRolesAnywhereProperties.getEncodedPrivateKey())
                .encodedX509Certificate(awsRolesAnywhereProperties.getEncodedX509Certificate())
                .durationSeconds(awsRolesAnywhereProperties.getDurationSeconds())
                .region(awsRolesAnywhereProperties.getRegion())
                .asyncCredentialUpdateEnabled(true)
                .prefetch(true)
                .build();
        return rolesAnywhereCredentialsProvider;
    }

    // pass the credentials provider as anyone would generally do
    @Bean
    S3Client s3Client(final AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider,
                      final AwsRolesAnywhereProperties awsRolesAnywhereProperties) {
        return S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider).region(Region.of(awsRolesAnywhereProperties.getRegion())).build();
    }

}

Example application properties, strictly coupled with AwsRolesAnywhereProperties
# AWS account id
aws.account.id=111111111111
# AWS region for the aws roles anywhere, actual AWS resource client may use a different region
aws.roles.anywhere.region=us-east-1
# AWS IAM roles anywhere trusted role
aws.roles.anywhere.role-arn=arn:aws:iam::${aws.account.id}:role/ROLES_ANYWHERE_S3_READ_ONLY
# AWS IAM roles anywhere profile
aws.roles.anywhere.profile-arn=arn:aws:rolesanywhere:us-east-1:${aws.account.id}:profile/a-random-long-id
# AWS IAM roles anywhere trust anchor
aws.roles.anywhere.trust-anchor-arn=arn:aws:rolesanywhere:us-east-1:${aws.account.id}:trust-anchor/a-random-long-id
# AWS IAM roles anywhere session duration
aws.roles.anywhere.duration-seconds=900
# AWS IAM roles anywhere access related private key, in pem format, base 64 encoded
aws.roles.anywhere.encoded-private-key=removed for security and brevity
# AWS IAM roles anywhere access related X509 Cert, in pem format, base 64 encoded
aws.roles.anywhere.encoded-x509-certificate=removed for security and brevity

